# iOS Launch Screen for app with different themes?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, themes, launch

I would like to create a launch screen(s) for my app which gives user an option to choose a theme (black or white).

What is the best approach to create a launch screen when I don't know what theme will be used at start-up?

Any advice will be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not program `LaunchScreen.storyboard` the alternative way is create a `ThemeViewController` for example and setup your app's appearance there,then check if user selected a theme skip that view controller to your app main view controller.You can detect if user select a theme using `NSUserdefualts`.

My suggestion is create a default theme for your app then if users would like to change it they will go to Settings and change the theme.

Comment: Thanks. I have a button there which on tap changes value (0 or 1) of NSUserdefaults. Colors across the app are then set accordingly to the value. Let's say the default value will be 0 (white) - launch screen will also be white. How can I make the app to automatically change launch screen to black when a user selects black theme (value 1)? Please can you give me any example code (in Swift)?

Comment: I told you there is no way to customize `LaunchScreen.storyboard` with code. You can just add image , labels and etc ... but via Interface Builder not code. One of the standard way is my suggestion.

Comment: I thought there might be a way to update the launch screen when app is running (not when launching) to prepare it for next launch.

Comment: Check this out :
https://github.com/granoff/LaunchScreen
It might help you . good luck. If you found this answer helpful please accept it . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible.

When launch screen is being displayed your app will be in loading state.

Even the

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

will not be completely executed while the launch screen is displayed.

So it's clear that, you don't have any access to your app and so at this point you can't execute any code and so - can't customize `LaunchScreen.xib`.